# how to resolve expected string or Unicode, float found

Tags: python, string, unicode, int

I'm trying to put a velocity reading on my window but keep getting expected unicode object, float found.

I've tried changing the velocity to a string and am having no luck. each of the attributes can be printed on the terminal including velocity but I can't get it to work in the cv2.putText function.

```
dY = pts[-10][1] - pts[i][1] - distance traveled in 10 counts
px_cm = diameter / obj_size
diff_count = 10.0
fps = 6.0
time = diff_count / fps


Ydistance = float(dY / px_cm)

if Ydistance >5:
     velocity = (Ydistance / time) 
     velocity = str(velocity)
     cv2.putText(frame, velocity, (10,500), font, 4,
         (255,255,255), cv2.LINE_AA)
elif Ydistance ==0.0:
   continue:
```

thanks in advance!!

```
class test (type)
    def __str__(self)
    return str.__class__

class vtest (object)
    self.repr(str)
```

Comment: what python version? you've tried `print(type(velocity))`? Otherwise your problem may not be in the exact part of code you have posted. Can you provide a more complete stacktrace?

Comment: it's a float! i removed the float from Distance = float (dY / px_cm) and got the same results back.
dY = pts[-10][1] - pts[i][1]    - distance traveled in 10 counts
px_cm = diameter / obj_size //

diff_count = 10.0 , fps = 6.0 
time = diff_count / fps

Comment: Have you tried with unicode casting? For example, velocity=unicode(velocity) @Sprice

Comment: just gave that a try and it still remains a float, would encoding work in this situation?

Comment: have you overridden the `str` builtin anywhere? that's pretty much the only thing that could cause this. try calling `repr(str)` and `str.__class__` what do you get?

Comment: As far as I'm aware no I haven't, I mean I haven't used str in my code. I'm new to coding so not completely sure what to put. I've googled it and still not too sure. I have pasted what I've got in the main question

Comment: How do you know it's velocity and not some other variable that is a float? Can you provide the complete stack trace, as already asked? What Python version are you using? And what's with the random, incomplete code fragments at the end of the post? How do they relate to your problem?

Comment: I used the print(type()) and all the variables involved are floats. sorry wasn't sure how to do a stack trace and still arent. 
I'm using python 2.7  
and because Arron mentioned using str.__class__ ...
I managed to change the velocity to float by creating a class that converts a variable to string and that worked. But now I'm getting an 'invalid syntax' on cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

Comment: The stack trace (or traceback) is the information you get on the command line when an exception terminates your program. And for the 'invalid syntax': There are a lot of syntax errors in your code fragments posted here...